# Magento 2.4.6 - any way to make Memcached work - Please Help!

Tags: magento2, session, memcached, magento2.4.6, core-session

Is there any way to configure memcached to work on Magento for session storage. Let's say it works, and you can really see the difference, especially in the admin backend.

Everything works fine until, for example, when I open Catalog / Products and need to load 200+ products per page, problems arise there.

**env.php:**

```
    'session' => [
    'save' => 'memcached',
    'save_path' => '127.0.0.1:11211'
],
```

**First i got red box with text:**

"A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later."

**Browser console:**

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

```
https://xxxxx.xx/xxxxxxxxxxx/mui/bookmark/save/key/aa0e91ea2ab9dc5b54161be5a9695013137eecb6ff5c3a215d9efb22f254f828/?isAjax=true
```

**Var/report:**

```
{"0":"Warning: SessionHandler::read(): Unable to clear session lock record in \/home\/customer\/www\/xxx\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SaveHandler\/Native.php on line 24","1":"#1 SessionHandler->read() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SaveHandler\/Native.php:24]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\Session\\SaveHandler\\Native->read() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SaveHandler.php:212]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\Session\\SaveHandler->callSafely() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SaveHandler.php:125]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\Session\\SaveHandler->read()\n#5 session_start() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SessionManager.php:186]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\Session\\SessionManager->start() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Model\/Auth\/Session\/Interceptor.php:149]\n#7 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Session\\Interceptor->start() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SessionManager.php:123]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\Session\\SessionManager->__construct() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/Model\/Auth\/Session.php:105]\n#9 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Session->__construct() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Model\/Auth\/Session\/Interceptor.php:14]\n#10 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Session\\Interceptor->__construct() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:121]\n#11 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:66]\n#12 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#13 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:170]\n#14 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:276]\n#15 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:239]\n#16 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:34]\n#17 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]\n#18 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#19 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:170]\n#20 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:276]\n#21 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:239]\n#22 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:34]\n#23 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]\n#24 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#25 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:206]\n#26 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->parseArray() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:182]\n#27 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:276]\n#28 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:239]\n#29 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:34]\n#30 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]\n#31 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#32 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:109]\n#33 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->__construct() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:14]\n#34 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->__construct() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:121]\n#35 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:66]\n#36 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#37 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:115]\n#38 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:264]\n#39 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub\/index.php:30]\n","url":"\/admin_nxxi29\/mui\/bookmark\/save\/key\/aa0e91ea2ab9dc5b54161be5a9695013137eecb6ff5c3a215d9efb22f254f828\/?isAjax=true","script_name":"\/pub\/index.php","report_id":"2cd732cb68493b03475a72e06fe6f989c1248e988a1d2e3b489c96f5f5038795"}
```

**Log/exception.log:**

```
main.critical: Exception: Warning: SessionHandler::read(): Unable to clear session lock record in /home/customer/www/xxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 24 in /home/customer/www/xxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:62
```

**Log/system.log:**

```
[2023-05-08T01:22:33.197921+00:00] main.ERROR: Warning: SessionHandler::read(): Unable to clear session lock record in /home/customer/www/xxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 24 [] []
```

**Setup:**

Magento CE 2.4.6,
4 CPUs,
8 GB RAM,
50 GB SSD

I beg you for help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.